# Error with implode array in php 5.3.9

Tags: php, arrays, quotes, implode

Trying to create an array in a specific format for the google chart API, but im getting an error with the implode function. I found this exmaple but im getting an error with 
`( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in C:\wamp\www\sqltest\sqltester.php on line 22` Line 22 is the implode line, think i may need extra quotes based on what php.net says but I'm doing it wrong.

```
//Your database query goes here
$list = mysql_query("SELECT city,crimes FROM TABLE");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($list)){
$data[] = "['".$row['city']."', ".$row['crimes']."]";
}

$data_for_chart = implode(",\n"$data);
```

**Looking for an output like this to be used in the google chart api**

```
     ['Cardiff', 300],
     ['London', 900],
     ['Manchester', 500],
     ['Dublin', 400],
     ['Liverpool', 600]
     ]);
```

Comment: `implode(",\n"$data);` - you're missing a comma in the middle of `"$`

Comment: Do you need newlines at all though?

Comment: You don't need to do all that messing around with strings to build a json input for an API -- PHP has a built-in function `json_encode()` that is designed for this.

Comment: Also, please be aware that PHP's `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. It is recommended to switch to a more modern DB api such as the PDO library.

Comment: Im using PDO in my real system, but i just drew up a quick example. Thanks :-) now gotta figure out how to upgrade my php from 5.1. without breaking the existing geoserver. Json seems the way forward if i can upgrade easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing comma here:

```
$data_for_chart = implode(",\n"$data);
// ---------------------------^
```

This should be:

```
$data_for_chart = implode(",\n", $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing comma

```
$data_for_chart = implode(",\n", $data);
```